# How corretly debounce react native animation

Tags: react-native, expo, react-animated, react-native-elements

I'm building an translateY e opacity component to animate my submit button that appears at the end of the form. The problem is that everytime the prop changes too fast the button stops working

```
[...]

class ShyButton extends PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { height: 0, visible: props.isVisible }
    this.animatedValue = new Animated.Value(props.isVisible ? 1 : 0)
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    const { isVisible } = this.props

    if (prevProps.isVisible !== isVisible) {
      if (isVisible) { this.toggleVisibility(prevState, true) }

      Animated.timing(this.animatedValue,
        { toValue: isVisible ? 1 : 0, duration: 800, useNativeDriver: true }
      ).start(() => { if (!isVisible) { this.toggleVisibility(prevState, false) } })
    }
  }

  toggleVisibility = (prevState, visible) => this.setState({ ...prevState, visible })

  onLayout = event => this.setState({ height: event.nativeEvent.layout.height })

  render() {
    const { isVisible, style, children, ...props } = this.props
    const { height, visible } = this.state
    const animatedStyle = {
      opacity: this.animatedValue.interpolate({
        inputRange: [0, 1],
        outputRange: [0, 1],
      }),
      transform: [
        {
          translateY: this.animatedValue.interpolate({
            inputRange: [0, 1],
            outputRange: [height, 0],
            extrapolate: 'clamp'
          })
        }
      ]
    }
    const combinedStyle = StyleSheet.flatten([style, { opacity: 0, transform: [{ translateY: 0 }] }])
    const animatingStyle = StyleSheet.flatten([combinedStyle, animatedStyle])
    return (
      <Animated.View onLayout={this.onLayout} style={visible ? animatingStyle : combinedStyle} {...props}>
        {visible ? children : null}
      </Animated.View>
    )
  }
}

[...]
```

The biggest problem is when auto-correct is used on the first word the text length goes to zero (test used to show or hide it) and back too fast, blocking the animation

[Imgur](https://i.imgur.com/MPFHE6M.mp4)

Comment: I've ran into a similar issue recently and the fix was to reset the animation before starting it again. So where you do `if (isVisible) { this.toggleVisibility(prevState, true) `, also add `this.animatedValue.setValue(0)` in there - this will ensure that the animation is starting from 0.

I'm also unsure whether you need to be passing `prevState` into `toggleVisibility`, maybe it's reasons that aren't visible in the code example.